# Как лучше сделать установку СMS на хост?

Tags: php, cms

Использую PHP 5.4 и Smarty. Есть два варианта:

1. Сделать один шаблон, для всех страниц установки, но контент присваивать разный, к примеру, на странице настроек БД, это будет таблица с несколькими колонками "пользователь, имя базы, пароль, порт, тип бд", каждую колонку создавать путем `$html->addRow($input_element_params)`, и потом выводить html в тело шаблона.
2. Сделать шаблон для каждой страницы, со всеми присущими им полями (они все равно не будут меняться, только текст, т.к. система мультиязычная), и в соотв. полях таблицы просто проставить переменные smarty, и в скрипте в них уже передавать массив со строками в нужном языке.

Я пока не знаю, как лучше сделать, опыта в этом еще пока ноль, не дадите ли какой совет?  Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать шаблон для каждой страницы, со всеми присущими им полями (они все равно не будут меняться, только текст, т.к. система мультиязычная), и в соотв. полях таблицы просто проставить переменные smarty, и в скрипте в них уже передавать массив со строками в нужном языке.